# API Mocking - How do I implement request forward while using a Javascript mock?

Tags: karate

I am aware that in a mock server feature file, it is possible to forward requests to a specific endpoint using `karate.proceed()`: https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-netty/#karateproceed.

We recently decided to opt for Javascript mocks, as they enable us to write more complex business logic for simulating the API we consume. Is there out-of-the-box functionality equivalent to `karate.proceed()` that I can use in a JS mock? Is there a way I can invoke `karate.proceed()` within this mock? Or is one expected to write Javascript code to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, and yes there is no `context.proceed()`. You need to use [`context.http()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Karate-JavaScript-Mocks#contexthttp) and manually create a new request and handle the response. All the data you need will be on the [`request`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Karate-JavaScript-Mocks#request) object. For example `request.method` will give you the HTTP method as a string.

This is indeed an un-documented part of Karate, yet to become "mainstream". Feel free to add a feature request for a `context.proceed()` that will auto-use the `request` in scope, that does sound useful. If you could contribute a PR or two that would be awesome :)

Comment: Thank you Peter. We will try and make a contribution here.